# How to prevent jupyterlab to load deleted extensions?

Tags: pip, jupyter, jupyter-lab

i've just uninstalled jupyter_tabnine extension:

```
pip3 install jupyter-tabnine
jupyter nbextension uninstall --py jupyter_tabnine
pip3 uninstall jupyter-tabnine
```

The problem is when i launching `jupyter lab` it still trying to load this module.

In terminal i see:

```
[W 2021-03-27 18:28:22.010 ServerApp] The module 'jupyter_tabnine' could not be found. Are you sure the extension is installed?
```

How to completely remove jupyter_tabnine so no warning messages appeared?

Comment: There must be an old configuration file that mentions it. Check files in directories listed under config when running `jupyter --paths` and remove references to jupyter-tabnine if you find any.

Comment: Thank you! there was reference in jupyter_notebook_config.json. Now it fixed

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for a solution to this question, the correct way to do this is by typing:

```
jupyter server extension disable jupyterlab_latex
```

which adds the file `$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupyterlab_latex.json`. For a system-wide modification, type:

```
sudo jupyter server extension disable jupyterlab_latex
```

which creates the file  `/usr/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupyterlab_latex.json`.

Alternatively, you can add the file by hand with the following content:

```
{
  "ServerApp": {
    "jpserver_extensions": {
      "jupyterlab_latex": false
    }
  }
}
```

Note that these commands were tested using JupyterLab 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

**For Win 10 Users:**
The extension was RAM consuming, and not working.
I followed all the steps above and yet it persisted.
I found the extension installed on this folder:

```
C:\Users\--\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\
```

I deactivated it on Task Manager, than just deleted it.